# Change you requested was rejected issue in production ( RAILS 6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

I have rails 6 app running in production. I am using load balancer and two dashboard servers(d1 and d2). They both have same secret_key_base in them but different master.key. I am consistenly facing this issue on d1. Previously secret_key_base was different on each server so I thought having both of them same will sort out the issue but this is not the case in my view right now because I am still getting this issue on my d1 server. d2 server is fine but I dont know why and how. Error ss is attached below.

[image]

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-01-29 11:29:58 +0500
I, [2024-01-29T11:29:58.069581 #46746]  INFO -- : [b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2024-01-29T11:29:58.069638 #46746]  INFO -- : [b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"V38ZddJOJOTEGOs8AuscUnhFHb8/02DW1hD0cQY2t3yuJQwVc5GOrN557F3pAEUiz04bMpUmLE/yEfPY9gZKNw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"ansm6927@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
W, [2024-01-29T11:29:58.070552 #46746]  WARN -- : [b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
I, [2024-01-29T11:29:58.070741 #46746]  INFO -- : [b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (Allocations: 954)
F, [2024-01-29T11:29:58.071201 #46746] FATAL -- : [b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709]   
[b21faa00-fb11-479a-b646-9920137ea709] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

Comment: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

Comment: I mean, if the `credentials.yml.enc` file you're deploying to both servers is the same, then you need the same `master.key` (or more often, `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env var) to decrypt that file. I suspect one of your servers can't decrypt its credentials, including its `secrey_key_base`